# Is there anyway to re-write this in a more appealing list comprehension format?

Tags: python

What I have here is hard to read and I was wondering how I could write this in fewer lines of code.

```py
lst = [-3,10.5,100]

def add_index(nums):
    lst2=[]
    add = 0
    for i in nums:
        add += 1
        lst2.append(i+add)
    return lst2
    
add_index(lst)
```

Comment: You can use `[(n + (index + 1)) for index, n in enumerate(lst)]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For each iteration of your loop, `add` contains a 1-based index and `i` contains the corresponding list item. There’s a built-in Python function called [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) that yields each item from an iterable along with its index as an `(index, item)` tuple.

Example of its use with your loop:

```py
lst2 = []
for i, x in enumerate(nums, start=1):
    lst2.append(x + i)
return lst2
```

which leads to a list comprehension equivalent:

```py
def add_index(nums):
    return [x + i for i, x in enumerate(nums, start=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use enumerate with an initial value of 1 to pair the list's numbers with the value to add and map the sum function to perform the addition on each pair:

```
def add_index(nums): return [*map(sum,enumerate(nums,1))]
```

Of do the addition in a comprehension if you find it more readable:

```
def add_index(nums): return [add+num for add,num in enumerate(nums,1)]
```